# Digital trimmer capacitor

Tags: arduino, capacitor

We would like to design an FM transmitter module for Arduino boards. Therefore, we are in need of a trimmer capacitor that can be controlled digitally. Do digital trimmer capacitors exist or do you have other ideas how to design such a module?

Comment: Varactor diode and a DAC.

Comment: For coarse tuning maybe telecom relays and a range of fixed caps.

Comment: I've done an edit to make it sound like less of a shopping question, but were you planning to use it to do just the FM modulation or did you have in mind that it would be setting the carrier frequency? A simple diagram of what you have in mind would be good.

Comment: As @ChrisStratton says, or a varactor and a digital pot.

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways to frequency-modulate a signal than changing a capacitance, but that's one of them.  Look up something called a *varactor diode*.  This is a diode whos purpose is to be a voltage-controlled capacitor.  The diode is reverse biased.  As the reverse voltage accross it changes, the size of the depletion region changes, changing the capacitance across the junction.

To control it digitally, use one of the many ways of converting digital values to a analog voltage.  Low pass filtering the PWM out of a microcontroller is one simple way, assuming you already have a micro in the system.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to generate radio signals using a DDS (direct digital synthesis) chip. There are many low-cost devices available from Analog Devices and other manufacturers, and they are very easy to interface to microcontrollers, including Arduino.